# How to pass stack ghci RTS options?

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm looking for something like

```
$ stack ghci -- Main.hs +RTS -M20M
Cannot use 'stack ghci' with both file targets and build targets
```

As this workaround is not recommended (why?):

```
stack exec -- ghci Main.hs +RTS -M20M
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, that is indeed a very poor error message.  I've created an issue for this - https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3342 - and implemented a fix, so that the next release of stack will instead say

> The following errors occurred while parsing the build targets:
>   - Directory not found: +RTS
>   - Directory not found: -M20M
>
> Note that to specify options to be passed to GHCi, use the --ghci-options flag

Instead running `stack ghci Main.hs --ghci-options '+RTS -M20M'` with released stack will yield:

> ghc: unknown RTS option: -ghci-script=/tmp/ghci29580/ghci-script

Because the user arguments are not passed to the end.  I've fixed that too.  For now, you can use `stack ghci Main.hs --ghci-options '+RTS -M20M -RTS'`